# How to handle multiple asynchronous post method in angular js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

```
$scope.savekbentry = function (value) {
        console.log('save clicked');
        console.log(value);
        console.log($scope.kbentry.kbname);

        $scope.kbentry.mode = value;
        var kbname = $scope.kbentry.kbname;
        var kbdescription = $scope.kbentry.kbname;
        var kbmode = "";
        var type = "";
        if ($scope.kbentry.mode == 'symptom') { kbmode = 1; type = 'SYM' }
        if ($scope.kbentry.mode == 'allergy') { kbmode = 3; type = 'ALG' }

        $http.post('../AjaxRequestData.aspx/AddKBEntry', { KB_Name: kbname, KB_Des: kbdescription, KB_Mode: kbmode })
        .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {

            $scope.transport = {
                method: 'post',
                read: '../WM_Autocomplete/GetAutocompleteData.aspx/GetSingletonLst',
                params: { type: type }
            }
        })
        .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {

        });

        clear();
    }
```

In the above code I wanted to call another asynchronous post method after success of first post. Currently its not working as per above code. How to handle this by call back functions?

Comment: where is the second post in above code ?

Comment: Check after success of first post

Answer (score 1):

You can use `then()` to chain and resolve `$http` request promises, eg:

```
var getSingletonPromise = function(type){
  return $http.post('.../GetSingletonLst', type) // returns a promise 
};

var addEntryPromise = function(params){
  return $http.post('.../AddKBEntry', params)  // returns a promise
};

$scope.savekbentry = function (value) {

  addEntryPromise().then(function(){ // use then() to resolve your promise
    // addEntry onSuccess
  }).getSingletonPromise().then(function(){
      // addEntry onSuccess
    }); 
}
```

You might also consider seperating the $http requests into a seperate factory/service and adding error handeling. 
Note that the above code has not been tested but provides an outline of a possible solution.